# How to make muesli/granola bars crunchier?

Tags: oven, oats, granola

I made a simple muesli bar yesterday, and being lazy, I just left it in the dehydrator for some 3-4 good hours or so. The mix is composed of the following ingredients:

- Oats mix (the ones that are already a mix)
- Wheat germ
- A bit of chocolate whey protein (the kind bodybuilders use)
- Unsalted whole peanuts

I just mixed them with honey and milk, spread them to even thickness (around 1 inch?) on top of a baking sheet, and put them in the food dehydrator for said 3-4 hours.

The taste turned out OK (it seems to have lost some sweetness from dehydration?) but it's not crunchy enough.

Would leaving it on the dehydrator (on the highest heat) longer do the trick for making it crunchy, or would I have to use the oven no matter what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the oven. The dehydrator will obviously remove water, but it won't toast the granola like an oven would.

You could always try super-dehydrating half a batch and ovening another.