# how to make health bar hold (stick) together

Tags: date-fruit, granola

Much to my surprise - this came out cake like instead of crunchy semi-hard granola bar.  Asking for advice to save money and time.  I thought of eliminating the egg or possibly adding more egg white?  or maybe no cream? or don't use butter? Obviously, I'm not a scientist.

By the way, mixture "tasted" very good.

1 Cup Old Fashioned Oatmeal.

1/2 Cup each of the following:
toasted coconut, sunflower seeds, sesame seeds, pumpkin seeds, chopped walnuts and slivered almonds.  Also 1/2 C very fine grounded sunflower seeds. (Maybe this turned into a cake?  What would've happened if I didn't add this.)

1/2 C Raisins, dried cranberries and dates

In pan, melted together 1/2 C Honey, 1/4 C unsalted butter, then when cooled, added 1 egg and 1/4 C cream, and 1 tsp vanilla.

Poured over dry mixture, coat all evenly, pressed tightly into 9x13 pan to 
bake for 30-40 mins. until top is lightly brown. Let cool completely before cutting into squares.

Comment: if you slice it right and bake again, you could end with something hard and crunchy like biscotti.  Since you liked the taste.  Not sure how to get to granola bar, though, sorry.

Comment: Is this something you created yourself or something that you found a recipe for somewhere? If the latter, please cite the source of the recipe.

Comment: related : http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/11088/67 ; http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/11399/67

Comment: Don't have a dehydrated & have no desire to get one.

Comment: I created this recipe in search of matching a health bar from a bakery.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise omitting the cream, as you mentioned yourself. It's a liquid, and combined with the ground sunflower seeds, eggs, butter, honey, and vanilla in the bottom of the pan, chances are good that that was your "cake." If things seem too dry as you mix them together, I would suggest adding another egg—it will help stick things together and add moisture without being as likely to stay moist, which is probably what created the cake texture. Eggs solidify with heat, they don't just evaporate like milk or cream.

Answer (score 1):

If I read your question correctly, you are wanting to create something more like a commercial "granola bar" and not like a cake.

Warm your honey and butter till it flows smoothly and you can mix it with your dry ingredients to get your desired consistency. Press this into your pan and bake for 15-20 minutes. While that bakes mix the ground sunflower seeds, egg, cream and vanilla separately. After par baking the granola, pour the 'cake batter' over the granola (you just want a thin layer here, so you may need to tweak your volumes here, and you might mix in some chocolate, or may I just want to add chocolate here). This should maintain your flavor profile and get you the 'granola like' texture you are after. Continue to bake until top layer passes 'the toothpick test'...and cool.